# How do I get sash_place() to work on startup?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter PanedWindow and if I use sash_place(0,50,50) with a function, it works just as desired. If, whoever, I want to place it initially, it does nothing. How can I place the sash on startup?

```
import Tkinter as tk

def move():
    allContent.sash_place(0,100,100)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1280x720+80+50")

# the toolbar
toolBar = tk.Frame(root, bg="blue")
toolBar.pack(anchor="nw")
# buttons
button_2 = tk.Button(toolBar, text="move", command=move)
button_2.pack(side="left",)

# main window
allContent = tk.PanedWindow(root, background="red", orient="horizontal", relief="ridge", bd=5, sashrelief="raised")

contentLeft = tk.Frame(allContent)
allContent.add(contentLeft)

contentRight = tk.Frame(allContent)
allContent.add(contentRight)
allContent.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

statusBar  = tk.Label(root, text="Status")
statusBar.pack(anchor="sw") 

allContent.sash_place(0,100,100) # How do I get this to work here?

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `allContent.update()` before `allContent.sash_place`.  This works for me with 3.4.2.  I got the idea from [here](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-tkinter-discuss/3459/), which said to use update_idletasks, which does not work, and which only showed code without either.

Comment: Great. That worked. And if I call it before packing, it seems to be a very clean solution. YAY!

Comment: Seems like I actually could ( :